# Protected routes in react-redux app, React router is not working as expected

Tags: reactjs, authentication, redux, react-router, react-router-v4

I have passport strategy with express server on backend. I have set up all the passport strategies and authentication. Now I need to protect some of my Routes. I am using redux to store the status whether the user is logged in or not.

I have tried creating a Private route according to this [tutorial](https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-protected-routes-authentication/). But it got into infinite loop (infinite rendering of the component).

Following code successfully connects to redux store , dispatches an action, and backend is also working fine.

But please suggest me why am i into infinate loop.

My Protected function looks like :

```
const login = {
  type: "Login"
};
const logout = {
  type: "Logout"
};
const AUTH =
  process.env.NODE_ENV === "production"
    ? "https://birdiez.herokuapp.com/auth/check"
    : "http://localhost:3090/auth/check";

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
  <Route
    {...rest}
    render={props => {
      console.log("calling api");
      fetch(AUTH)
        .then(response => {
          return response.json();
        })
        .then(data => {
          console.log("Promise resolved:", data);
          data.msg === "OK" ? store.dispatch(login) : store.dispatch(login);
        });
      const { status } = store.getState();
      return status === true ? (
        <Component {...props} />
      ) : (
        <Redirect
          to={{
            pathname: "/",
            state: { from: props.location }
          }}
        />
      );
    }}
  />
);
export default PrivateRoute;
```

My App.js looks like :

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
          <PrivateRoute path="/dash" component={Dash} />
          <Route exact path="*" component={Home} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```